# Restart server if gateway is not responding

Tags: monitoring, ping

I need to restart a windows 2008  server only if the gatwaay is not responding. Is there a way to conditionally ping the gateway and if the gateway is not reachable a restart is triggered?

Thank you

Comment: Restart the gateway, or the server? Or is the server the gateway?

Comment: I was trying to figure out why you'd need to restart a server if the gateway was down. O_o

Comment: @Nixphoe - I need to restart the actual sever. Its happening that when the link is down , the firewall service crashes and the only way to recover is by restarting the whole server.I am really struggling with this one. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a better option to contact the firewall vendor to see what you can't do to get those services started with out a reboot (seriously though). But to do what you're asking, you could try running this batch script, have it start up with Task Scheduler on reboot. You could either loop it with the "goto start" option listed. Or remove that and just have Task Scheduler run it every 5 minutes.

```
:start
ping [gatewayIP]
if %errorlevel%==1 shutdown /r 
goto start
```

Comment: thank you for the batch script. I understand that this is only a dirty workaround, but it avoids me having to check in at unholy hours ! As regards vendors I am checking since on the firewall I have a third party content filtering product and I am monitoring to see if this could be the culprit.